# How to add multiple data in sql table with html and php form

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I am beginner here. I have a record like this in my SQL Table

```
id    name_id    score
1     N_1         98
2     N_3         78
3     n_3         68
```

I have a HTML and PHP set of code that display a table with an input fields next to each of its ID's and Name which looks like
**CONSIDER [ ] AS INPUT FIELDS**

```
ID     NAME       SCORE
N_4    James      []
N_5    Kit        []
N_6    Chino      []
```

When I put some scores into it just like

```
ID     NAME       SCORE
N_4    James      [98]
N_5    Kit        [76]
N_6    Chino      [81]
```

My SQL table should look like this

```
id    name_id    score 
1     N_1         98
2     N_2         78
3     N_3         68
4     N_4         98
5     N_5         76
6     N_6         81
```

But instead of inserting 3 rows of data in my SQL Table it just insert as one, just look like this

```
id    name_id    score 
1     N_1         98
2     N_2         78
3     N_3         68
4     N_4         98
```

What should I do? Here is some of my code

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT l_name, f_name, m_name, sid FROM tbl_student WHERE section='".$_POST['section']."';"; ?>
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>NAME</th>
                                <th>Score</th>
                            </tr>    
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <?php $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                                    while ($resultset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                                    <tr>
                                    <form method="post">
                                    <td><?php echo $resultset ['sid']; ?></td>
                                    <td style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $resultset ['l_name']; echo ", "; echo $resultset ['f_name']; echo " "; echo $resultset ['m_name'];?></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" name="grade"></td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultset ['sid']; ?>">
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                        </table> 
                                    <button class="pull-right btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit_tbl_grade">SAVE</button>
                                    </form>
                    <?php } ?>
                        <?php if(isset($_POST['submit_tbl_grade'])){
                            $name = $_POST['grade'];
                            $id =   $_POST['id'];
                            $record = "INSERT INTO tbl_grade(stud_id,component_value) VALUES ($id,$name)";
                            mysqli_query($db,$record);
```

Comment: you have only one insert statement, and its not in a loop, therefore there is only one insert. If you use a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) you can execute it with the other values. You'll also need to give each input in the loop a different name.

Comment: i got it. Thank you that was so useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input tags like below.

```
<input type="text" style="width:50px;" name="grade[]">
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $resultset ['sid']; ?>">
```

Then you can access the values like below,

```
$name = $_POST['id'][0]
$id = $_POST['grade'][0]
```

Using a loop you can access the values and insert them to DB.

Comment: Its working. Thank you, it was so useful. that helped me a lot :) Godbless